# Windows 7 media player libary issue

Tags: windows-media-player

For some reason I no longer have music in my MS media player. When I click on Organize then manage libraries then music, I get nothing. The attached window "Music Library Locations" should be displayed, but it doesn't. The music is still on my hard drive and will play if clicked on. I've gone through the "Turn Windows Features On and Off" process and have run malware, virus and registry cleaners with no positive results. I also dis a restore from the earliest point available. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the `Music` library and then restore the default libraries, does that help? Instructions are [here](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-error-library-ms-is-no-longer-working-windows-7/). Note that this won't affect your actual music files or folders.